# What is causing the "run" button in my menu bar to stack?

Tags: html, css

It's taken me a ridiculous amount of work to get this menu bar looking clean, which is a problem in and of itself. However, I think it's finally coming together. The problem I'm having now is three-fold.

Two questions:

1. When this is viewed full screen, the menu bar looks great, but as you close in the screen the "run" button drops to the bottom. What is causing this?
2. How come if I keep closing the window, the middle .toggle list is stacking on top of the "CodePlayer" logo? What do I need to do to make it so that when the window shrinks, the divs get to the point where they'd begin to overlap and stop?
3. Why is there a tiny bit of gap between the border-right and bottom-border in the middle section of my menu? I've tried 0px padding and it isn't working.

http://jsfiddle.net/ow5zq9fL/

```
/*-----------UNIVERSAL------------*/
    body {
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
        font-weight: 300;
    }

/*-----------MENU BAR------------*/


    #menuBar {
        height: 40px;
        background-color: gray; 
        max-width: 100%; 
    }

/*------LOGO, TOGGLES, BUTTON-----*/


    #logo,
    #buttonDiv,
    #toggles {
        vertical-align: middle; 
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
        height: 18px;
    }

/*-----------LOGO------------*/


    #logo {
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 1em; 
        font-family: helvetica; 
        vertical-align: middle; 
        position: relative; 
        top: 12px; 
        left: 12px; 
/*      background-color: blue; 
*/
    }

/*-----------TOGGLES------------*/


    .toggles {
        text-align: center; 
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative; 
        top: -9px;
        width: 300px; 
        left: 20px;
    }


    .toggles li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 1px solid black; 
   }
/*----------TOGGLES LIST----------*/

    #resultList {
        border-right: none; 
    }



/*-------------BUTTON------------*/


    #buttonDiv {
        text-align: right; 
        position: relative; 
        top: 8px;
        right: 12px;
        vertical-align: middle;       
    }

/*-----------BUTTON------------*/


    #htmlList {
        padding-right: 20px; 
        margin-left: -20px;     
    }

    #cssList {
        padding: 0 25px;    
    }

    #jsList {
        padding: 0 25px;  
    }

    #resultList {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }



</style>
```

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="menuBar">

        <div id="logo">CodePlayer</div>

        <div id="toggles">
            <ul class="toggles">
                <li id="htmlList">HTML</li>
                <li id="cssList">CSS</li>
                <li id="jsList">JS</li>
                <li id="resultList">Result</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="buttonDiv">

            <button id="runButton">Run</button>

        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ow5zq9fL/3/). I added a wrapper and applied everything from `#buttonDiv` to `.wrapper`. Then I altered it so that it was centered.

**New Code:**

```
 .wrapper {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

**and**

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="buttonDiv">
            <button id="runButton">Run</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked, but I'm not really sure why? Also, how would I then prevent the button from going over the middle section when the screen is shrunk?

Comment: aha, only looked at your first problem @mellamojoe . I'll try and figure something out for 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float` left

```
 #logo, #buttonDiv, #toggles {
    ...
    float: left;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/ow5zq9fL/4/**